# Adding a column with unique values in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

So, I am looking for a way to sequence the rows of my athena table. I have already tried:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
```

But then this leads to `Query exhausted resources at this scale factor` error. It has to be a unique value for every row, so yes it doesn't need to be an integer. The method should be performance effective if it can be.

Comment: can you add the full query that you are running? exhausted ressources might nit be due to the `row_number`

Answer (score 1):

You can give each row a unique id, `uuid`, using the `uuid()`  function. Here are the docs:

https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/uuid.html

Comment: `uuid()` is only available in AWS Athena version 3, which is based on Trino, and is not available in AWS Athena version 2, which is based on Presto.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming Athena is based on MySQL...*

*Please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.

If you don't already have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column on the table, consider the following.

```
ALTER TABLE t
    ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ADD INDEX(id);
```

If you don't already have a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table, do this *instead*:

```
ALTER TABLE t
    ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

Comment: AWS Athena does not support `AUTO_INCREMENT` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html

Comment: @dossy - Are you sure Athena is a "database"?  Every _real_ database has some form of "sequence" for generating surrogate ids.  Maybe Athena is only useful for reaching into other datasets, and only reads the entire table, without regard for Updates, etc.

Comment: @RickJames Athena supports iceberg which allows for updates that has both DML and DDL. It's not an OLTP it's an OLAP. Also what athena doesn't have is its own storage layer, it operates on parquet and other formats. So things like enforcing constraints, indexes and things that need centralization aren't features in Athena. And no it's not a "database" it's a query service.

Comment: @KitSunde - I'm changing your tags; please do not tagl with `[mysql]` if that database engine is not involved.

Comment: @RickJames Not my question my dude.